# Calling a method in itself as a method

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

So , basically i am trying to create a input field and when i enter a number it gives me the desired child of the same html. 
now i want child to produce more children with unique name with javascript.
i am attaching the code for a better understanding.

```
<div class="row" id="child_nr">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
<div class="form-group col-xs-4">
<label for="name" class="control-label">Parameter Name: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-8">
<input type="text" class="form-control required" id="param_name" name="param_name" placeholder="name" onblur="param()"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
<div class="form-group col-xs-3">
<input type="text" class="form-control required" id="parent_nr" name="parent_nr" value="0" onblur="param()"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-5">
<label for="name" name="service_code" id="service_code" class="control-label">
Service Code </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control required" name="service_code" id="service_code"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script language="javascript">

function param(){
    var value=parent_nr.value;
    const name=document.getElementById("param_name").value;
    for(var i=1;i<=value;i++)
    {
        const html='<div class="col-xs-12"><div class="form-group col-xs-6"><div class="form-group col-xs-7"><label for="name" class="control-label">Parameter Name'+i+': <font color="red">*</font></label></div><div class="form-group col-xs-5"><input type="text" class="form-control required" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name"/></div></div><div class="form-group col-xs-6"><div class="form-group col-xs-3"><input type="number" class="form-control required" id="parent_nr" name="parent_nr" value="0" onblur="param()"/></div><div class="form-group col-xs-5"><label for="name" name="service_code" id="service_code" class="control-label">Service Code </label></div><div class="form-group col-xs-4"><input type="text" class="form-control required" name="service_code" id="service_code"/></div></div></div>';
        document.querySelector('#child_nr').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',html);
        }
    }


function sendData() {
    var question = 'abc';
    var c = 'cde';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/gtiemr/addnewparameter_laboratory',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { question: question, c: c },
        success: function () {
            alert('suc');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}   

</script>
```

Also, i want to know  how i can send the value to my controller using ajax so that i can send it to model.

Comment: I find it unclear, is it me or there is no apparent link between your title and your post? Where exactly do you want to "Call a method in itself as a method", and what does it mean to you? Why is it related to "producing more children with unique name"?

Comment: the function param in js is used in itself in html variable , have a look

Comment: i want to store these values at a same time in the database so their name needs to be unique